# Как, в данном случае, работает & в if?

Tags: java, циклы, if, битовые-операции

Почему при написании программы, которая бы сравнивала отдельные элементы массива и выводила самое большое значение, у меня в итоге последнее значение как будто не учитывается значение. В результате мне пишет `MaxNumber - 5`, хотя должно быть `MaxNumber - 9`.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {-7, 5, -1, 3, 9,};
    if (array[0]>(array[1] & array[2] & array[3] & array [4])) {
        System.out.println("Max Number - " + array[0]);
        int MaxNumber = array[0];
    }
    else if (array[1]>(array[0] & array[2] & array[4] & array [3])) {
        System.out.println("Max Number - " + array[1]);
        int MaxNumber = array[1];
    }
    else if (array[2] > (array[0] & array[1] & array[3] & array [4])) {
        System.out.println("Max Number - " + array[2]);
        int MaxNumber = array[2];
    }
    else if (array[3] > (array[0] & array[2] & array[1] & array[4])) {
        System.out.println("Max Number - " + array[3]);
        int MaxNumber = array[3];
    }
    else if (array[4] > (array[0] & array[2] & array[3] & array [1])) {
        System.out.println("Max Number - " + array[4]);
        int MaxNumber = array[4];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Вот, по-Вашему, что делает? - `(array[1] & array[2] & array[3] & array [4])`

Comment: Почитайте про битовые операции

Comment: @AzizUmarov тут ему не нужны битовые операции, он не так пишет сравнения через &&

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да скорее всего так. Но ТП не понимает что делает и разницу между логическими и битовыми операциями

Comment: @AzizUmarov да, ключевое тут "не понимает что делает" ))

Comment: @AzizUmarov что-то я не понимаю. Но ведь можно же делать сравнение через &? Просто если &&, то последние условия не будут проверяться, если первое условие false. Если &, то в любом случае будут проверены все условия.

Comment: @AzizUmarov тут скорее из-за того, что у него всё это дело в скобках, ничего не работает нормально.

Comment: @Zhenyria все возможно. Не отрицаю

Answer (score 0):

Перепишите условие

```
if ((array[0]>array[1]) && (array[0]>array[2]) && (array[0]>array[3]) && (array[0]>array[4]))
```

Но вы как-то сложным путём пошли. Можно проще. Да и есть команды, для определения максимального числа с массиве